# jQuery change focus to next input when entered string reaches a specific character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see a lot of scripts for changing input text field focus with max length, but I can't seem to find any that will move the cursor to the next field when the text in the current field reaches a specific character.  The reason I need this is because input will have different length, so max length can't be used.  For example, I will type in abcd1234!.  The exclamation mark (!) will be the key for the script to change focus to the next field. I'm using the following script to generate my text fields.

```
    <div id="myDiv">
    <input type="text" name="qr[]" id="txt_1" autofocus />
</div>
<script>
$('#myDiv').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).next().remove();
        return;
    }
    else if($(this).next().val() == '') {
        console.log('here');
        return;
    }

    var newTxt = $(this).clone();
    var id = newTxt.attr('id');
    newTxt.attr('id', 'txt_' + (parseInt(id.substring(id.indexOf('_') + 1))));
    newTxt.val('');
    $(this).parent().append(newTxt);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want the `!` to show up in either of the fields?

Comment: Is there a specific reason/requirement that `!` be the character? With proper `tabindex` attributes, the tab key will do this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/uej260wL/1/)** that does what you want.

```js
$('#myDiv').on('keyup', 'input', function (e) {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).next().remove();
        return;
    } else if ($(this).next().val() == '') {
        if (e.keyCode === 49 && e.shiftKey) {
            $(this).next().focus();
        }
        return;
    }

    var newTxt = $(this).clone();
    var id = newTxt.attr('id');
    newTxt.attr('id', 'txt_' + (parseInt(id.substring(id.indexOf('_') + 1))));
    newTxt.val('');
    $(this).parent().append(newTxt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
    <input type="text" name="qr[]" id="txt_1" autofocus />
</div>
```

Basically, I am checking to see if the event (that's the first parameter in the function) is key code 49 (the <kbd>1</kbd>) key and that the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed. Then I am focusing the next element.

Comment: I noticed a small issue.  These fields would be populated using a QR code scanner.  When I type the string with the keyboard, the exclamation mark is detected and switches the field.  However, when I copy/paste the code, including the exclamation mark, the cursor remains in the same field.  The same happens when using the barcode scanner to fill the field.  Any ideas how this can be resolved?

Comment: @user5075858, I recommend asking a new question about that here on SO. That will make it easier for other people with the same question to find.

Comment: I just did.  Thanks!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209697/jquery-to-switch-to-next-field-using-barcode-reader

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like that. In my example you just switch from one field to second.
But if you have a lot of fields with same class and need to switch from one to another you can use the length of items array to switch to a definite input.

```js
$('#one').on('input', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value[value.length-1] == '!') {
       $('#two').focus();
       }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="one">
<input type="text" id="two">
```